# OpenShift, how to start ode Apache server

Tags: tomcat, openshift, ode, openshift-client-tools

I have installed Tomcat 8 via DIY on OpenShift and I deployed ODE.war via the web browser, through ManagerApp in tomcat page, Now I'm stuck on how to start ode server? or even how to start Tomcat server?